# Send JPA Wrapper Object

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, business-logic, toplink

I created structure for separate **business-logic** of `@Entities`, I did `@Entity` like **POJO** and this extends in something like a `BO` contains **business-logic** and **validations**.

I think send my `"BO"` for **CRUD** but problem are when I want **read** return me `@Entity` object (I don´t know if I must create converter or something) but when I want **create, update or delete** return me error says `"BO"` is not know `@Entity` (I know this but I should some way to take **father class**).

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

entity class

```
@Entity
```

public class Employee {

```
protected String id;

protected String name;

protected float salary;

protected Employee() { }

public final String getId() {
    return id
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public final String getName() {
    return name
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public final float getSalary() {
    return salary
}
public void setSalary(float salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}

My BO:

```
public class EmployeeBO extends Employee{

public EmployeeBO(String id, String name, float salary) {
    setId(id);
    setName(name)
    setSalary(salary);
}
public  final void setSalary(float salary) {
    //bussines logic
}
public final void setName(String name) {
    //bussines logic
}
public final void setId(String id) {
    //bussines logic
}
```

}

And then I work only EmployeeBO. For example `em.remove(employeeBO)`

Comment: I think you may need to add some simple code snippets to help explain more clearly what you asking. Do you mean you have entity objects that need to be business objects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your business layer should operate on top of your data layer and be organized into logically connected groups. Something like this:

```
public class EmployeeInfoOperations {

    public final void updateName(Employee employee, String newName) {
        //bussines logic: trigger name update on external systems?
    }
    public final void updateContactAddress(Employee employee, Address newAddress) {

    }
}

public class EmployeeAccounting {

    public  final void changeSalary(Employee employee,float newSalary) {

    }

    public final void giveBonus(Employee employee, bigdecimal bonusAmount) {
    }
}
```

Your bussiness operation classes don't even have to be centric around one entity type. Think about group of business operations, small enough to become one class, and use any entity types as arguments.

Comment: I think this more like service layer. I think if change name of employee always do it same bussines logic I should validate when I change name (in set) and this logic not repeat in other Entity.

Comment: service layer, business logic - in my view we speak about same thing. if you have bussiness logic to change employee name, then create a service function for that and use in other business services. you can stack service functions if you need to.